# Which is faster? Dereferencing pointers or using square brackets?

Tags: c

In my program an array is accessed millions of times. Is it faster to access the contents of the array by dereferencing the pointer like this, *(arr + i), instead of using square brackets?

Comment: It really depends on which machine you are using.  AS400 has 32 byte (not bit) pointers.   Are you using AS400?

Comment: `*(arr+i)` *is* `arr[i]` ... (for an array, as specified in the question, thus not a duplicate of array vs pointer)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of array vs pointer.

Comment: Hello @Double_O_Seven, welcome to Stack Overflow
You can check the difference using: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos: That's a great piece of advice but slightly imprecise. Godbolt is great for showing you what particular compilers do, but it can't tell you they're formally equivalent as well.

Comment: Indeed, theory and practice could be different. That's why one of the greatests mistakes/advantages of C is the equivalence between `*a`, `*(a + 0)` and `a[0]`. Demonstrating this with the assembly equivalent of a basic code involves this trick helps to solve this question.

Comment: There is effectively no difference in performance between the two (they *should* result in identical machine code).  The question you *should* be asking is, "which is easier to read and understand," or "which am I less likely to make a mistake with."  The answer to both is to use bracket notation, `arr[i]`.

Answer (score 8):

As Ring Ø noted in a comment, they are identical by definition; if there is any difference in how they perform, it's nothing but intentional badness on the part of the compiler.

Comment: What about `ptr + offset` vs `&ptr[offset]`? They also should be exactly the same, but the latter, at least if you go step by step, does more and is redundant, does compiler also optimize this?

Comment: @PurpleIce: They do mean exactly the same thing. According to the standard, `&*` is a no-op. ("If the operand [of the `&` operator] is the result of a unary `*` operator, neither that operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted..." [6.5.3.2/3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p3))

Answer (score 1):

`*(arr+i)` is the equivalent of `arr[i]`.  A compiler would be expected to emit the same code.

As with such style issues, code to your group's coding guidelines, which I expect to be `arr[i]`.

With no  guidelines, code for clarity. [@John Bode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057267/which-is-faster-dereferencing-pointers-or-using-square-brackets#comment93034231_53057267)